# call function in object without accessing object property

Tags: javascript

here i have a confusion i create object called `obj` obj has a key `first`.
a `first` key has a key `second` now when i interpret below program its called function 
`hello()` and give output on console  `hello`. without accessing object property like `obj.first.second`.
i didn't understand whats going on

or is there any way to prevent function call before accessing object property.

```js
var obj ={
first:{
    second:hello("hello")
  }
}
 
 //obj.first.second

function hello(url){
   console.log(url)
 }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: `obj.first.second` would be `undefined` because when you write `hello("hello")` and assign it to the key `second` as a value, you are calling the function `hello()` with the parameter `"hello"`, so the function is executed and writes `hello` to the console and returns nothing back which is assign to the key `second` as a value of undefined.

Comment: You can also set `second` to just `hello` (not string), so that later you can pass the string to it to print to console like `obj.first.second("hello") // hello`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for a getter, that gets executed when you access the property:

```js
 var obj = {
  first: {
     get second() { hello("hello") }
   }
};

 function hello(url) {
   console.log(url);
 }
 // Now here hello gets called:
 obj.first.second
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use getter with define your objects with class.

here is an example

```js
class Rectangle {
      constructor(height, width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
      }
      // Getter
      get area() {
        return this.calcArea();
      }
      // Method
      calcArea() {
        return this.height * this.width;
      }
    }

    const square = new Rectangle(10, 10);

    console.log(square.area);
```